# How to get dynamically created html <audio> tag in php

Tags: php, dom, html5-audio

I am trying to read the html `<audio>` tag in PHP, But it is creating dynamically

This is [the URL](https://www.thisamericanlife.org/680/the-weight-of-words)! I'm using to read

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach (iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('audio')) as $node) {
  $this->printnode($node);
}
```

In `printnode()` function it is showing like no `<audio>` tag exits because it is creating dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the structure, yes the url for the actual audio is being loading dynamically via JS.

But the audio playlist data is still visible. Use that:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$playlist_data = $xpath->evaluate('string(//script[@id="playlist-data"])');
$data = json_decode($playlist_data, 1);
echo $data['audio'];
```

Its inside another script tag on JSON string format. So basically, access this data and get the value as a string. Then you'll get the JSON string, and as usual, load it into `json_decode` and the parser will do its thing returning you with an array, then access the audio url like any normal array

Sidenote: I just used `xpath` as personal preference, you can use:

```
$playlist_data = $dom->getElementById('playlist-data')->nodeValue;
```

if you choose to do so.

Comment: here a [fiddle](https://www.tehplayground.com/AB1f7BOMI9zJe6WO) by the way